# How do you add Author and date Published on Category Pages?

Tags: categories, author, title, date-time, customization

I made a category on my Wordpress site.

when i write any post and tag it in the category, the post displaying on the category pages in a neat way, everything is fine.

But Google webmaster tools are saying

**Missing: author**

**Missing: entry-title**

**Missing: updated**

on the category pages.

*I am using [wowwy](http://themeforest.net/item/wowway-interactive-responsive-portfolio-theme/2374321) theme*

Here is the theme's Structure

```
(404.php)
Archives
(archive.php)
Attachment Template
(attachment.php)
Comments
(comments.php)
contact-form.php
content.php
Footer
(footer.php)
Theme Functions
(functions.php)
Header
(header.php)
aq_resizer.php
contact-form.php
custom-styles.php
customizer-options.php
extend-ot.php
krown-shortcodes-config.php
krown-shortcodes.php
krown-update.php
metaboxes.php
plugins.php
portfolio-functions.php
theme-options.php
widget.php
Main Index Template
(index.php)
loop.php
ot-loader.php
Page Template
(page.php)
Search Results
(search.php)
single-gallery.php
single-portfolio.php
Single Post
(single.php)
Blog Page Template
(template-blog.php)
Contact Page Template
(template-contact.php)
Gallery Page Template
(template-gallery.php)
Portfolio Page Template
(template-portfolio.php)
Fullscreen Slideshow Page Template
(template-slideshow.php)
Fullscreen Video Page Template
(template-video.php)
```

can anyone suggest me how can i add author, date and title on the category pages ?

Comment: can you please paste the code inside your category template ?

Comment: Nope, there is no catagory named tamplate in my theme struture

Comment: Can you tell me the name of your theme and if you can paste the php code from category.php file.

Comment: I updated theme and file's structures in my question

Comment: See this regarding how WP looks for category template files. http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#What_Template_File_is_Used.3F You will need to create a template if one is not included with your theme.